# How do I send data from my userform to a seprate spreadsheet in different cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that searches for certiam criteria based on a cell. Once the user form pulls the data I can update the data on that same spreadsheet but what I need to do is send this data to a different spreadsheet. The data will be in different cells then what is pulling the data from. Make since? My code is below. Any help is appriciated.

```
 Option Explicit
Private Sub AddWithValue(Text As String, Value As String)

    lbxDate_Of_Incident.AddItem Text
    lbxDate_Of_Incident.List(lbxDate_Of_Incident.ListCount - 1, 1) = Value

End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click()
Dim rng     As Range
'This will Edit all information on this form
    With lbxDate_Of_Incident
        If .ListIndex <> -1 Then
            Set rng = Range(.List(.ListIndex, 1))
            '' now get all of offsets of it here
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B1").Value = tbxPatientName.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B2").Value = txbMonth.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B3").Value = txbYear.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B4").Value = lbxDate_Of_Incident.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D1").Value = Code_Rapid_Response.Text
                'Potassium
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B8").Value = TextBox1.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C8").Value = TextBox2.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D8").Value = TextBox3.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E8").Value = TextBox4.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F8").Value = TextBox5.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G8").Value = TextBox6.Text
                'Sodium
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B9").Value = TextBox7.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C9").Value = TextBox8.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D9").Value = TextBox9.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E9").Value = TextBox10.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F9").Value = TextBox11.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G9").Value = TextBox12.Text
                'Calcium
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B10").Value = TextBox151.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C10").Value = TextBox14.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D10").Value = TextBox15.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E10").Value = TextBox16.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F10").Value = TextBox17.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G10").Value = TextBox18.Text
                'Creatinine
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B11").Value = TextBox19.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C11").Value = TextBox20.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D11").Value = TextBox21.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E11").Value = TextBox22.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F11").Value = TextBox23.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G11").Value = TextBox24.Text
                'BUN
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B12").Value = TextBox25.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C12").Value = TextBox26.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D12").Value = TextBox27.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E12").Value = TextBox28.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F12").Value = TextBox29.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G12").Value = TextBox30.Text
                'WBC
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B14").Value = TextBox31.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C14").Value = TextBox32.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D14").Value = TextBox33.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E14").Value = TextBox34.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F14").Value = TextBox35.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G14").Value = TextBox36.Text
                'Neut ABS
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B15").Value = TextBox37.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C15").Value = TextBox38.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D15").Value = TextBox39.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E15").Value = TextBox40.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F15").Value = TextBox41.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G15").Value = TextBox42.Text
                'Platelets
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B16").Value = TextBox43.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C16").Value = TextBox44.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D16").Value = TextBox45.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E16").Value = TextBox46.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F16").Value = TextBox47.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G16").Value = TextBox48.Text
                'RBC
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B17").Value = TextBox49.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C17").Value = TextBox50.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D17").Value = TextBox51.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E17").Value = TextBox52.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F17").Value = TextBox53.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G17").Value = TextBox54.Text
                'HCT
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B18").Value = TextBox55.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C18").Value = TextBox56.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D18").Value = TextBox57.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E18").Value = TextBox58.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F18").Value = TextBox59.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G18").Value = TextBox60.Text
                'HGB
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B19").Value = TextBox61.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C19").Value = TextBox62.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D19").Value = TextBox63.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E19").Value = TextBox64.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F19").Value = TextBox65.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G19").Value = TextBox66.Text
                'PH
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B21").Value = TextBox67.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C21").Value = TextBox68.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D21").Value = TextBox69.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E21").Value = TextBox70.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F21").Value = TextBox71.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G21").Value = TextBox72.Text
                'PO2
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B22").Value = TextBox73.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C22").Value = TextBox74.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D22").Value = TextBox75.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E22").Value = TextBox76.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F22").Value = TextBox77.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G22").Value = TextBox78.Text
                'PCO2
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B23").Value = TextBox79.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C23").Value = TextBox80.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D23").Value = TextBox81.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E23").Value = TextBox82.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F23").Value = TextBox83.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G23").Value = TextBox84.Text
                'O2 Requirement
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B24").Value = TextBox85.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C24").Value = TextBox86.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D24").Value = TextBox87.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E24").Value = TextBox88.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F24").Value = TextBox89.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G24").Value = TextBox90.Text
                'Vitals
                'Pulse Oximetry
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B26") = TextBox109.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C26") = TextBox110.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D26") = TextBox111.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E26") = TextBox112.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F26") = TextBox113.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G26") = TextBox114.Text
                'Systolic
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B27").Value = TextBox91.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C27").Value = TextBox92.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D27").Value = TextBox93.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E27").Value = TextBox94.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F27").Value = TextBox95.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G27").Value = TextBox96.Text
                'Diastolic
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B28") = TextBox97.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C28") = TextBox98.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D28") = TextBox99.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E28") = TextBox100.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F28") = TextBox101.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G28") = TextBox102.Text
                'Heart Rate
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B29") = TextBox103.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C29") = TextBox104.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D29") = TextBox105.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E29") = TextBox106.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F29") = TextBox107.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G29") = TextBox108.Text

                'Temp
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B30") = TextBox115.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C30") = TextBox116.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D30") = TextBox117.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E30") = TextBox118.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F30") = TextBox119.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G30") = TextBox120.Text
                'res Rate
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B31") = TextBox121.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C31") = TextBox122.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D31") = TextBox123.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E31") = TextBox124.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F31") = TextBox125.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G31") = TextBox126.Text
                'Neuro Status
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B33") = Neuro_72hrs.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C33") = Neuro_60hrs.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D33") = Neuro_48hrs.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E33") = Neuro_36hrs.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F33") = Neuro_24hrs.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G33") = Neuro_12hrs.Text


        End If
    End With

End Sub


Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
'This Button will Search for records

    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim Search      As Range
    Dim found       As Range
    Dim patient     As String
    Dim lbxValue    As String
    Dim firstFind   As String

    lbxDate_Of_Incident.Clear

    patient = tbxPatientName.Text

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        '' define our search range (Column A)
        Set Search = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        '' search that range for the patient's name
        Set found = Search.Find(patient, SearchDirection:=xlNext, After:=ws.Range("A1"))

        '' test if we found anything
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            firstFind = found.Address

            Do
                '' found something, add it to the text box
                lbxValue = "'" & found.Parent.Name & "'!" & found.Address(External:=False)
                AddWithValue found.Offset(, 1).Value, lbxValue

                Set found = Search.Find(patient, SearchDirection:=xlNext, After:=found)
            Loop While Not found Is Nothing And found.Address <> firstFind
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub lbxDate_Of_Incident_Change()

    Dim rng     As Range

    With lbxDate_Of_Incident
        If .ListIndex <> -1 Then
            Set rng = Range(.List(.ListIndex, 1))
            '' now get all of offsets of it here
                txbMonth.Text = rng.Offset(, 2)
                txbYear.Text = rng.Offset(, 3)
                'Potassium
                TextBox1.Text = rng.Offset(, 20)
                TextBox2.Text = rng.Offset(, 49)
                TextBox3.Text = rng.Offset(, 78)
                TextBox4.Text = rng.Offset(, 107)
                TextBox5.Text = rng.Offset(, 136)
                TextBox6.Text = rng.Offset(, 165)
                'Sodium
                TextBox7.Text = rng.Offset(, 21)
                TextBox8.Text = rng.Offset(, 50)
                TextBox9.Text = rng.Offset(, 79)
                TextBox10.Text = rng.Offset(, 108)
                TextBox11.Text = rng.Offset(, 137)
                TextBox12.Text = rng.Offset(, 166)
                'Calcium
                TextBox151.Text = rng.Offset(, 22)
                TextBox14.Text = rng.Offset(, 51)
                TextBox15.Text = rng.Offset(, 80)
                TextBox16.Text = rng.Offset(, 109)
                TextBox17.Text = rng.Offset(, 138)
                TextBox18.Text = rng.Offset(, 167)
                'Creatinine
                TextBox19.Text = rng.Offset(, 23)
                TextBox20.Text = rng.Offset(, 52)
                TextBox21.Text = rng.Offset(, 81)
                TextBox22.Text = rng.Offset(, 110)
                TextBox23.Text = rng.Offset(, 139)
                TextBox24.Text = rng.Offset(, 168)
                'BUN
                TextBox25.Text = rng.Offset(, 24)
                TextBox26.Text = rng.Offset(, 53)
                TextBox27.Text = rng.Offset(, 82)
                TextBox28.Text = rng.Offset(, 111)
                TextBox29.Text = rng.Offset(, 140)
                TextBox30.Text = rng.Offset(, 169)
                'WBC
                TextBox31.Text = rng.Offset(, 25)
                TextBox32.Text = rng.Offset(, 54)
                TextBox33.Text = rng.Offset(, 83)
                TextBox34.Text = rng.Offset(, 112)
                TextBox35.Text = rng.Offset(, 141)
                TextBox36.Text = rng.Offset(, 170)
                'Neut ABS
                TextBox37.Text = rng.Offset(, 26)
                TextBox38.Text = rng.Offset(, 55)
                TextBox39.Text = rng.Offset(, 84)
                TextBox40.Text = rng.Offset(, 113)
                TextBox41.Text = rng.Offset(, 142)
                TextBox42.Text = rng.Offset(, 171)
                'Platelets
                TextBox43.Text = rng.Offset(, 27)
                TextBox44.Text = rng.Offset(, 56)
                TextBox45.Text = rng.Offset(, 85)
                TextBox46.Text = rng.Offset(, 114)
                TextBox47.Text = rng.Offset(, 143)
                TextBox48.Text = rng.Offset(, 172)
                'RBC
                TextBox49.Text = rng.Offset(, 28)
                TextBox50.Text = rng.Offset(, 57)
                TextBox51.Text = rng.Offset(, 86)
                TextBox52.Text = rng.Offset(, 115)
                TextBox53.Text = rng.Offset(, 144)
                TextBox54.Text = rng.Offset(, 173)
                'HCT
                TextBox55.Text = rng.Offset(, 29)
                TextBox56.Text = rng.Offset(, 58)
                TextBox57.Text = rng.Offset(, 87)
                TextBox58.Text = rng.Offset(, 116)
                TextBox59.Text = rng.Offset(, 145)
                TextBox60.Text = rng.Offset(, 174)
                'HGB
                TextBox61.Text = rng.Offset(, 30)
                TextBox62.Text = rng.Offset(, 59)
                TextBox63.Text = rng.Offset(, 88)
                TextBox64.Text = rng.Offset(, 117)
                TextBox65.Text = rng.Offset(, 146)
                TextBox66.Text = rng.Offset(, 175)
                'PH
                TextBox67.Text = rng.Offset(, 31)
                TextBox68.Text = rng.Offset(, 60)
                TextBox69.Text = rng.Offset(, 89)
                TextBox70.Text = rng.Offset(, 118)
                TextBox71.Text = rng.Offset(, 147)
                TextBox72.Text = rng.Offset(, 176)
                'PO2
                TextBox73.Text = rng.Offset(, 32)
                TextBox74.Text = rng.Offset(, 61)
                TextBox75.Text = rng.Offset(, 90)
                TextBox76.Text = rng.Offset(, 119)
                TextBox77.Text = rng.Offset(, 148)
                TextBox78.Text = rng.Offset(, 177)
                'PCO2
                TextBox79.Text = rng.Offset(, 33)
                TextBox80.Text = rng.Offset(, 62)
                TextBox81.Text = rng.Offset(, 91)
                TextBox82.Text = rng.Offset(, 120)
                TextBox83.Text = rng.Offset(, 149)
                TextBox84.Text = rng.Offset(, 178)
                'O2 Requirement
                TextBox85.Text = rng.Offset(, 34)
                TextBox86.Text = rng.Offset(, 63)
                TextBox87.Text = rng.Offset(, 92)
                TextBox88.Text = rng.Offset(, 121)
                TextBox89.Text = rng.Offset(, 150)
                TextBox90.Text = rng.Offset(, 179)
                'Vitals
                'Systolic
                TextBox91.Text = rng.Offset(, 35)
                TextBox92.Text = rng.Offset(, 64)
                TextBox93.Text = rng.Offset(, 93)
                TextBox94.Text = rng.Offset(, 122)
                TextBox95.Text = rng.Offset(, 151)
                TextBox96.Text = rng.Offset(, 180)
                'Diastolic
                TextBox97.Text = rng.Offset(, 37)
                TextBox98.Text = rng.Offset(, 66)
                TextBox99.Text = rng.Offset(, 95)
                TextBox100.Text = rng.Offset(, 124)
                TextBox101.Text = rng.Offset(, 153)
                TextBox102.Text = rng.Offset(, 182)
                'Heart Rate
                TextBox103.Text = rng.Offset(, 38)
                TextBox104.Text = rng.Offset(, 67)
                TextBox105.Text = rng.Offset(, 96)
                TextBox106.Text = rng.Offset(, 125)
                TextBox107.Text = rng.Offset(, 154)
                TextBox108.Text = rng.Offset(, 183)
                'Pulse Oximetry
                TextBox109.Text = rng.Offset(, 40)
                TextBox110.Text = rng.Offset(, 69)
                TextBox111.Text = rng.Offset(, 98)
                TextBox112.Text = rng.Offset(, 127)
                TextBox113.Text = rng.Offset(, 156)
                TextBox114.Text = rng.Offset(, 185)
                'Temp
                TextBox115.Text = rng.Offset(, 42)
                TextBox116.Text = rng.Offset(, 71)
                TextBox117.Text = rng.Offset(, 100)
                TextBox118.Text = rng.Offset(, 129)
                TextBox119.Text = rng.Offset(, 158)
                TextBox120.Text = rng.Offset(, 187)
                'Res Rate
                TextBox121.Text = rng.Offset(, 44)
                TextBox122.Text = rng.Offset(, 73)
                TextBox123.Text = rng.Offset(, 102)
                TextBox124.Text = rng.Offset(, 131)
                TextBox125.Text = rng.Offset(, 160)
                TextBox126.Text = rng.Offset(, 189)
                'Neuro Status
                Neuro_72hrs.Text = rng.Offset(, 46)
                Neuro_60hrs.Text = rng.Offset(, 75)
                Neuro_48hrs.Text = rng.Offset(, 104)
                Neuro_36hrs.Text = rng.Offset(, 133)
                Neuro_24hrs.Text = rng.Offset(, 162)
                Neuro_12hrs.Text = rng.Offset(, 191).Value



        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### In General

Without a qualifier, a `Range` object always refers to the `ActiveSheet`.

So since you are using syntax like:

```
rng.Offset(, 20)
```

it basically implies something like:

```
ActiveSheet.rng.Offset(, 20)
```

There are a few ways to refer to cells on other worksheets using range.

```
Sub RangeExample()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A5")
    
    'this is one way you can use a range object
    'on another worksheet
    Sheets(1).Range(r.Address).Value = "test"
    Sheets(2).Range(r.Address).Value = "test2"
    Sheets(3).Range(r.Address).Value = "test3"
    
    'you can use this to get a very specific
    'cell reference
    Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "test"
    Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = "test2"
    Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1) = "test3"

    'you can also do the following
    Set r = Sheets(3).Range("A5")
    r.Value = "testSheet3"

End Sub
```

`Range` doesn't work nicely with another `Range` object, so you cannot do something like:

```
Sheets(1).Range(rng)
```

won't work.

I generally prefer the use of `.Cells(row, column)` as this is just more clear nearly always when doing loops. Or the last option of the three I show.

---

### Your situation

In your case, change:

```
Set rng = Range(.List(.ListIndex, 1))
```

to

```
Set rng = Sheets(2).Range(.List(.ListIndex, 1))
```

will let you reference another worksheet.

Comment: It did not work. However after playing with it a few more hours I found a solution. The I have re-edited my code above to the code that works. Thank you for your response..

Answer (score 0):

I played with it a few more hours and figured out a solution below is the code.

```
    Option Explicit
Private Sub AddWithValue(Text As String, Value As String)

    lbxDate_Of_Incident.AddItem Text
    lbxDate_Of_Incident.List(lbxDate_Of_Incident.ListCount - 1, 1) = Value

End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click()
Dim rng     As Range
'This will Edit all information on this form
    With lbxDate_Of_Incident
        If .ListIndex <> -1 Then
            Set rng = Range(.List(.ListIndex, 1))
            '' now get all of offsets of it here
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B1").Value = tbxPatientName.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B2").Value = txbMonth.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B3").Value = txbYear.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B4").Value = lbxDate_Of_Incident.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D1").Value = Code_Rapid_Response.Text
                'Potassium
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B8").Value = TextBox1.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C8").Value = TextBox2.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D8").Value = TextBox3.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E8").Value = TextBox4.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F8").Value = TextBox5.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G8").Value = TextBox6.Text
                'Sodium
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B9").Value = TextBox7.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C9").Value = TextBox8.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D9").Value = TextBox9.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E9").Value = TextBox10.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F9").Value = TextBox11.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G9").Value = TextBox12.Text
                'Calcium
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B10").Value = TextBox151.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C10").Value = TextBox14.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D10").Value = TextBox15.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E10").Value = TextBox16.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F10").Value = TextBox17.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G10").Value = TextBox18.Text
                'Creatinine
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B11").Value = TextBox19.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C11").Value = TextBox20.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D11").Value = TextBox21.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E11").Value = TextBox22.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F11").Value = TextBox23.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G11").Value = TextBox24.Text
                'BUN
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B12").Value = TextBox25.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C12").Value = TextBox26.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D12").Value = TextBox27.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E12").Value = TextBox28.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F12").Value = TextBox29.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G12").Value = TextBox30.Text
                'WBC
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B14").Value = TextBox31.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C14").Value = TextBox32.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D14").Value = TextBox33.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E14").Value = TextBox34.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F14").Value = TextBox35.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G14").Value = TextBox36.Text
                'Neut ABS
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B15").Value = TextBox37.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C15").Value = TextBox38.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D15").Value = TextBox39.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E15").Value = TextBox40.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F15").Value = TextBox41.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G15").Value = TextBox42.Text
                'Platelets
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B16").Value = TextBox43.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C16").Value = TextBox44.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D16").Value = TextBox45.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E16").Value = TextBox46.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F16").Value = TextBox47.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G16").Value = TextBox48.Text
                'RBC
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B17").Value = TextBox49.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C17").Value = TextBox50.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D17").Value = TextBox51.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E17").Value = TextBox52.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F17").Value = TextBox53.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G17").Value = TextBox54.Text
                'HCT
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B18").Value = TextBox55.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C18").Value = TextBox56.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D18").Value = TextBox57.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E18").Value = TextBox58.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F18").Value = TextBox59.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G18").Value = TextBox60.Text
                'HGB
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B19").Value = TextBox61.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C19").Value = TextBox62.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D19").Value = TextBox63.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E19").Value = TextBox64.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F19").Value = TextBox65.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G19").Value = TextBox66.Text
                'PH
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B21").Value = TextBox67.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C21").Value = TextBox68.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D21").Value = TextBox69.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E21").Value = TextBox70.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F21").Value = TextBox71.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G21").Value = TextBox72.Text
                'PO2
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B22").Value = TextBox73.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C22").Value = TextBox74.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D22").Value = TextBox75.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E22").Value = TextBox76.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F22").Value = TextBox77.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G22").Value = TextBox78.Text
                'PCO2
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B23").Value = TextBox79.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C23").Value = TextBox80.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D23").Value = TextBox81.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E23").Value = TextBox82.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F23").Value = TextBox83.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G23").Value = TextBox84.Text
                'O2 Requirement
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B24").Value = TextBox85.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C24").Value = TextBox86.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D24").Value = TextBox87.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E24").Value = TextBox88.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F24").Value = TextBox89.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G24").Value = TextBox90.Text
                'Vitals
                'Pulse Oximetry
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B26") = TextBox109.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C26") = TextBox110.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D26") = TextBox111.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E26") = TextBox112.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F26") = TextBox113.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G26") = TextBox114.Text
                'Systolic
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B27").Value = TextBox91.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C27").Value = TextBox92.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D27").Value = TextBox93.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E27").Value = TextBox94.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F27").Value = TextBox95.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G27").Value = TextBox96.Text
                'Diastolic
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B28") = TextBox97.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C28") = TextBox98.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D28") = TextBox99.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E28") = TextBox100.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F28") = TextBox101.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G28") = TextBox102.Text
                'Heart Rate
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B29") = TextBox103.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C29") = TextBox104.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D29") = TextBox105.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E29") = TextBox106.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F29") = TextBox107.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G29") = TextBox108.Text

                'Temp
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B30") = TextBox115.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C30") = TextBox116.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D30") = TextBox117.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E30") = TextBox118.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F30") = TextBox119.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G30") = TextBox120.Text
                'res Rate
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B31") = TextBox121.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C31") = TextBox122.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D31") = TextBox123.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E31") = TextBox124.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F31") = TextBox125.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G31") = TextBox126.Text
                'Neuro Status
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("B33") = Neuro_72hrs.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("C33") = Neuro_60hrs.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("D33") = Neuro_48hrs.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("E33") = Neuro_36hrs.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("F33") = Neuro_24hrs.Text
                Worksheets("Charts_Information").Range("G33") = Neuro_12hrs.Text


        End If
    End With

End Sub


Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
'This Button will Search for records

    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim Search      As Range
    Dim found       As Range
    Dim patient     As String
    Dim lbxValue    As String
    Dim firstFind   As String

    lbxDate_Of_Incident.Clear

    patient = tbxPatientName.Text

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        '' define our search range (Column A)
        Set Search = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        '' search that range for the patient's name
        Set found = Search.Find(patient, SearchDirection:=xlNext, After:=ws.Range("A1"))

        '' test if we found anything
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            firstFind = found.Address

            Do
                '' found something, add it to the text box
                lbxValue = "'" & found.Parent.Name & "'!" & found.Address(External:=False)
                AddWithValue found.Offset(, 1).Value, lbxValue

                Set found = Search.Find(patient, SearchDirection:=xlNext, After:=found)
            Loop While Not found Is Nothing And found.Address <> firstFind
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub lbxDate_Of_Incident_Change()

    Dim rng     As Range

    With lbxDate_Of_Incident
        If .ListIndex <> -1 Then
            Set rng = Range(.List(.ListIndex, 1))
            '' now get all of offsets of it here
                txbMonth.Text = rng.Offset(, 2)
                txbYear.Text = rng.Offset(, 3)
                'Potassium
                TextBox1.Text = rng.Offset(, 20)
                TextBox2.Text = rng.Offset(, 49)
                TextBox3.Text = rng.Offset(, 78)
                TextBox4.Text = rng.Offset(, 107)
                TextBox5.Text = rng.Offset(, 136)
                TextBox6.Text = rng.Offset(, 165)
                'Sodium
                TextBox7.Text = rng.Offset(, 21)
                TextBox8.Text = rng.Offset(, 50)
                TextBox9.Text = rng.Offset(, 79)
                TextBox10.Text = rng.Offset(, 108)
                TextBox11.Text = rng.Offset(, 137)
                TextBox12.Text = rng.Offset(, 166)
                'Calcium
                TextBox151.Text = rng.Offset(, 22)
                TextBox14.Text = rng.Offset(, 51)
                TextBox15.Text = rng.Offset(, 80)
                TextBox16.Text = rng.Offset(, 109)
                TextBox17.Text = rng.Offset(, 138)
                TextBox18.Text = rng.Offset(, 167)
                'Creatinine
                TextBox19.Text = rng.Offset(, 23)
                TextBox20.Text = rng.Offset(, 52)
                TextBox21.Text = rng.Offset(, 81)
                TextBox22.Text = rng.Offset(, 110)
                TextBox23.Text = rng.Offset(, 139)
                TextBox24.Text = rng.Offset(, 168)
                'BUN
                TextBox25.Text = rng.Offset(, 24)
                TextBox26.Text = rng.Offset(, 53)
                TextBox27.Text = rng.Offset(, 82)
                TextBox28.Text = rng.Offset(, 111)
                TextBox29.Text = rng.Offset(, 140)
                TextBox30.Text = rng.Offset(, 169)
                'WBC
                TextBox31.Text = rng.Offset(, 25)
                TextBox32.Text = rng.Offset(, 54)
                TextBox33.Text = rng.Offset(, 83)
                TextBox34.Text = rng.Offset(, 112)
                TextBox35.Text = rng.Offset(, 141)
                TextBox36.Text = rng.Offset(, 170)
                'Neut ABS
                TextBox37.Text = rng.Offset(, 26)
                TextBox38.Text = rng.Offset(, 55)
                TextBox39.Text = rng.Offset(, 84)
                TextBox40.Text = rng.Offset(, 113)
                TextBox41.Text = rng.Offset(, 142)
                TextBox42.Text = rng.Offset(, 171)
                'Platelets
                TextBox43.Text = rng.Offset(, 27)
                TextBox44.Text = rng.Offset(, 56)
                TextBox45.Text = rng.Offset(, 85)
                TextBox46.Text = rng.Offset(, 114)
                TextBox47.Text = rng.Offset(, 143)
                TextBox48.Text = rng.Offset(, 172)
                'RBC
                TextBox49.Text = rng.Offset(, 28)
                TextBox50.Text = rng.Offset(, 57)
                TextBox51.Text = rng.Offset(, 86)
                TextBox52.Text = rng.Offset(, 115)
                TextBox53.Text = rng.Offset(, 144)
                TextBox54.Text = rng.Offset(, 173)
                'HCT
                TextBox55.Text = rng.Offset(, 29)
                TextBox56.Text = rng.Offset(, 58)
                TextBox57.Text = rng.Offset(, 87)
                TextBox58.Text = rng.Offset(, 116)
                TextBox59.Text = rng.Offset(, 145)
                TextBox60.Text = rng.Offset(, 174)
                'HGB
                TextBox61.Text = rng.Offset(, 30)
                TextBox62.Text = rng.Offset(, 59)
                TextBox63.Text = rng.Offset(, 88)
                TextBox64.Text = rng.Offset(, 117)
                TextBox65.Text = rng.Offset(, 146)
                TextBox66.Text = rng.Offset(, 175)
                'PH
                TextBox67.Text = rng.Offset(, 31)
                TextBox68.Text = rng.Offset(, 60)
                TextBox69.Text = rng.Offset(, 89)
                TextBox70.Text = rng.Offset(, 118)
                TextBox71.Text = rng.Offset(, 147)
                TextBox72.Text = rng.Offset(, 176)
                'PO2
                TextBox73.Text = rng.Offset(, 32)
                TextBox74.Text = rng.Offset(, 61)
                TextBox75.Text = rng.Offset(, 90)
                TextBox76.Text = rng.Offset(, 119)
                TextBox77.Text = rng.Offset(, 148)
                TextBox78.Text = rng.Offset(, 177)
                'PCO2
                TextBox79.Text = rng.Offset(, 33)
                TextBox80.Text = rng.Offset(, 62)
                TextBox81.Text = rng.Offset(, 91)
                TextBox82.Text = rng.Offset(, 120)
                TextBox83.Text = rng.Offset(, 149)
                TextBox84.Text = rng.Offset(, 178)
                'O2 Requirement
                TextBox85.Text = rng.Offset(, 34)
                TextBox86.Text = rng.Offset(, 63)
                TextBox87.Text = rng.Offset(, 92)
                TextBox88.Text = rng.Offset(, 121)
                TextBox89.Text = rng.Offset(, 150)
                TextBox90.Text = rng.Offset(, 179)
                'Vitals
                'Systolic
                TextBox91.Text = rng.Offset(, 35)
                TextBox92.Text = rng.Offset(, 64)
                TextBox93.Text = rng.Offset(, 93)
                TextBox94.Text = rng.Offset(, 122)
                TextBox95.Text = rng.Offset(, 151)
                TextBox96.Text = rng.Offset(, 180)
                'Diastolic
                TextBox97.Text = rng.Offset(, 37)
                TextBox98.Text = rng.Offset(, 66)
                TextBox99.Text = rng.Offset(, 95)
                TextBox100.Text = rng.Offset(, 124)
                TextBox101.Text = rng.Offset(, 153)
                TextBox102.Text = rng.Offset(, 182)
                'Heart Rate
                TextBox103.Text = rng.Offset(, 38)
                TextBox104.Text = rng.Offset(, 67)
                TextBox105.Text = rng.Offset(, 96)
                TextBox106.Text = rng.Offset(, 125)
                TextBox107.Text = rng.Offset(, 154)
                TextBox108.Text = rng.Offset(, 183)
                'Pulse Oximetry
                TextBox109.Text = rng.Offset(, 40)
                TextBox110.Text = rng.Offset(, 69)
                TextBox111.Text = rng.Offset(, 98)
                TextBox112.Text = rng.Offset(, 127)
                TextBox113.Text = rng.Offset(, 156)
                TextBox114.Text = rng.Offset(, 185)
                'Temp
                TextBox115.Text = rng.Offset(, 42)
                TextBox116.Text = rng.Offset(, 71)
                TextBox117.Text = rng.Offset(, 100)
                TextBox118.Text = rng.Offset(, 129)
                TextBox119.Text = rng.Offset(, 158)
                TextBox120.Text = rng.Offset(, 187)
                'Res Rate
                TextBox121.Text = rng.Offset(, 44)
                TextBox122.Text = rng.Offset(, 73)
                TextBox123.Text = rng.Offset(, 102)
                TextBox124.Text = rng.Offset(, 131)
                TextBox125.Text = rng.Offset(, 160)
                TextBox126.Text = rng.Offset(, 189)
                'Neuro Status
                Neuro_72hrs.Text = rng.Offset(, 46)
                Neuro_60hrs.Text = rng.Offset(, 75)
                Neuro_48hrs.Text = rng.Offset(, 104)
                Neuro_36hrs.Text = rng.Offset(, 133)
                Neuro_24hrs.Text = rng.Offset(, 162)
                Neuro_12hrs.Text = rng.Offset(, 191).Value



        End If

    End With

End Sub
```